# await page.waitFor inside page.evaluate in puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, time, puppeteer

I was wondering if you could do something like

```
 page.evaluate((page) => {
     //Code to execute before
     await page.waitFor(1000);
     //Code to execute after the 1000ms time delay
 }, page);
```

If this isn't possible, how would one introduce such a time delay?

Oh, final note, doing something like this isn't a viable option for time delay in my project:

```
 function delay(time) {
     let curtime = new Date().getTime();
     time += curtime;
     while(curtime < time) {
         curtime = new Date().getTime();
     } 
 }
```

CPU matters on this, and I don't wanna have some while loop executing thousands of times for a simple delay

Comment: you would need to make your arrow function `async` for the first code block to work (ie: `async (page) => {`)

Comment: This is the error I get from doing that: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON Are you passing a nested JSHandle?

Answer (score 8):

1. `await` can only be used in `async` functions.
2. The function in `evaluate` will be evaluated in the page context so either:

Use `setTimeout()`:

```js
page.evaluate(() => {
     //Code to execute before
     setTimeout(function() {
       //Code to execute after the 1000ms time delay
     }, 1000);    
 });
```

Or write your async delay function similar to `page.waitFor` in [puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/4ddbe2e53009896e8eb166dd18fb36e403e9a80d/experimental/puppeteer-firefox/lib/FrameManager.js#L325).

```js
function waitFor(delay) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, delay));
}
```

Then you will have:

```js
page.evaluate(async() => {
     //Define your waitFor function
     //Code to execute before
     await waitFor(1000);
     //Code to execute after the 1000ms time delay
 });
```